# Cant deploy to goerli

Tags: solidity, contract

Hey for some reason when I am trying to deploy my contract to georli on remix it asks for 0.1 eth and fails immediatly. When i deploy on VS code i get this error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!.

But it works perfectly fine on ganache. Also it worked on goerli yesterday before I went to bed. Anyone know why?

[image: Error in MM]

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the high traffic the goerli testnet is getting recently which is increasing the gas fee. I've been facing the high gas costs recently also.